# How to properly use when condition in Ansible

Tags: ansible

```yaml
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Checking project list
    shell: |
      argocd proj list | grep xcore

    register: argoProj
  - debug: var=argoProj.stdout

  - name: create a project if not exits
    shell: |
      argocd proj create xcore
      # when: argoProj.stdout != "xcore"
    when: argoProj.stdout.find('xcore')!=-1
```

Error:

```yaml
''
TASK [create a project if not exits] *****************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "argocd proj create xcore\n     \n# when: argoProj.stdout != \"xcore\"\n", "delta": "0:00:00.807940", "end": "2021-02-04 09:11:24.257123", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 20, "start": "2021-02-04 09:11:23.449183", "stderr": "time=\"2021-02-04T09:11:24Z\" level=fatal msg=\"rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = existing project spec is different, use upsert flag to force update\"", "stderr_lines": ["time=\"2021-02-04T09:11:24Z\" level=fatal msg=\"rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = existing project spec is different, use upsert flag to force update\""], "stdout": "EE: 0/[]", "stdout_lines": ["EE: 0/[]"]}
```

NOTE: I want to skip the last task when an xcore project is already created. The last task needs to execute when there is no project with same name.

Actual output of the shell command:

```sh
#argocd proj list | grep xcore
xcore                  gke_ec2nf-256816_us-central1_gke-devops,production  <none>                                           <none>                      <none>                        <none>          disabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```yaml
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Checking project list
      shell: argocd proj list | grep xcore
      register: argoProj

    - debug: var=argoProj.stdout

    - name: create a project if not exits
      shell: argocd proj create xcore
      when: "'xcore' not in argoProj.stdout"
```

Comment: The above fix working well for me. Thank you so Mr. Kevin C for the great help!

Comment: If you want to match `xcore` at the beginning of the line use [regex](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings)  `when: argoProj.stdout is not regex('^xcore\s+(.*)$')`

Comment: why not build this in the shell commando? `argocd proj list | grep xcore | awk '{print $1}'`